# How prove for any postive integer $k$,there exsit positive integer $a_{k}$,such $29^k\mid(a^3_{k}-9)$

Tags: number-theory

> show that: for any postive integer $k$,there exsit positive integer $a_k$, such
>   $$29^k\mid(a^3_{k}-9)$$

My idea: maybe I think we  How find the $a_k=f(k)?$

and this reslut have  a general?

thank you

Comment: The condition can be rewritten as $a_k^3 \equiv 9 \mod 29^k$.

Comment: yes,then I find the $a_{k}?$,Thank you

Comment: @ozo That fails for $k=1$.

Comment: @ozo,and How can sure $a_{k}$ is postive ineteger?

Comment: Start by finding a possible value for $a_1$. Note that for $k > 1$, the value $a_k$ also satisfies $a_k^3 - 9 \equiv 0 \pmod{29^{k-1}}$, so it would be a possible choice for $a_{k-1}$ too.

Comment: Have you bumped into Hensel lifting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First find a value $a_1$ with $a_1^3-9$ a multiple of 29.

Then, to find $a_2$, you can use $a_2=29b_1+a_1$.  Expand $(29b_1+a_1)^3-9$.  Ignore any multiples of $29^2$, then calculate $b_1$.

Next $a_3=29^2b_2+a_2$, and so on.

Comment: It's Nice! and you can find the minimum of the $a_{1}?$,Thank you

Comment: By inspection, the minimum positive $a_1$ is $5$.